# How to display connections from Oracle using Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsf

I want to create JSF page which displays Oracle connections. The web page will be hosted on Glassfish server. How I can get this information from Oracle with SQL query?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query displays all sessions, you can use `state`, `status`, `username`, `machine`, `program` and ... to retrieve information you want

```
select *
  from v$session
```